# what is a "dump file" in windows task manager?

Tags: windows, dump, taskmanager

I know that with windows you can generate a dump file by going to task manager->processes-> right clicking on the process.

1. what is a dump file ?
2. what can i do with .dmp file?

Answer (score 5):

A .dmp file is a *Minidump*, a snapshot of a live process containing information about its current state (including memory, stack traces, thread information, module information, exception context information). This information allows you to inspect a snapshot of a process. It is often generated when a process is about to crash due to an unhandled exception, but can be taken at any point.

It can be created using the [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) API, and opened with any Windows Debugger (like Visual Studio<sup>1)</sup> or [WinDbg, KD, CDB, NTSD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx)). See [Crash Dump Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349.aspx) for additional information.

---

*<sup>1)</sup> Depending on the information present in the Minidump file, Visual Studio may not be able to open a specific .dmp file. The other debuggers do not impose any restrictions, as far as I know.*

Answer (score 1):

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d5zhxt22.aspx a dump file is a snapshot of the application at that moment in time.

Dump files are used to aid debugging applications when they go wrong.