# Headless debugging on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, headless

There is a bug that I would like to fix that only occurs on Windows Server without a GUI running. I have set up a Windows Server 2019 machine on Google Compute Engine that reproduces the bug, and would like to debug it.

Ideally, I would like to use gdb, but seeing as the program was built with Visual Studio 2019, gdb can't read the debugging symbols.

I don't have a Windows machine, so using Visual Studio will be difficult. I could set up a VM, but if there's an in-terminal way to do this that would be preferred.

I did a pretty thorough Google search, but it didn't turn up anything. Is there really no Windows solution for debugging C++ code headlessly?

Comment: @KenWhite CMake running on a VM.

Comment: Then you do have the code. Excellent. I know of no console debugger for Visual Studio, but with the code you at least have hope of [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp?view=vs-2019) with a, um, ??headded?? Windows box if you can get or make one.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, it's looking like I might have to spin up a Windows VM with a GUI for this. I might try compiling with MinGW first though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS has 2 console debuggers called [CDB and NTSD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-cdb-and-ntsd) so you don't actually need Visual Studio GUI to do the debugging. In fact there are a lot of [debugging environments in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debuggers-in-the-debugging-tools-for-windows-package) from MS beside the usual Visual Studio. Just install them in your Windows Server and control them remotely from your terminal

You can also debug MSVC-compiled code with LLDB since the [PDB format](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-pdb) has been published long time ago and [LLVM on Windows does support it](http://blog.llvm.org/2017/08/llvm-on-windows-now-supports-pdb-debug.html). No idea about current LLDB on Linux though

And since you have the source code, sometimes the old-school `printf` debugger is the best way to analyze the issue

---

If you can get a Windows VM it'll be much better to do [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp?view=vs-2019). In fact almost all debuggers support that feature including GDB or LLDB, so even if you don't have the source code you can still run *any* Windows debugger and step through the instructions instead of high-level code lines from a remote machine

An alternative way is to take a [memory dump](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/254649/overview-of-memory-dump-file-options-for-windows) and **debug later**. After getting the dump file, just [drag it into your VS solution or any debugging tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019) like [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) and then select "Start Debugging". Now you can step through instructions/code lines and examine variables' values, or jump to an arbitrary function's stack frame just as if you're really running the malfunctioning app

There are many ways to dump a process' memory. You can set Windows to automatically save a dump file when your app crashes, or just capture memory snapshots manually during runtime. Comparing 2 snapshots is also useful for detecting leaked memory. For more information on how to do that read

- [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps)
- [Steps to Catch a Simple “Crash Dump” of a Crashing Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chaun/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process)

There's also an easy way to take a dump of a live process using [task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34252338/995714) [manager](https://superuser.com/q/1246211/241386) (or any other similar tools)

[image: Create dump file in task manager]