# Is it possible to use the Visual Studio debugger from command line?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, visual-studio-debugging, neovim

Im a beginner in C++ and I use NeoVim as my editor. I use MSVC++ build tools for compiling my programs. But when it comes to debugging, I don't want to open Visual Studio just for debugging. Is there any way I can debug my program from command line using visual studio debugger? Since GDB is the debugger that comes with g++, which debugger comes with msvc build tools?

I tried reading the visual studio documentations, but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: See [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools).  Also on the same page _"...There are four command line debuggers that are available for specialized environments and for those that prefer a command line interface..."_.  Also in my opinion the MSVS debugger is an order of magnitude easier to use than any of the command line tools.

Comment: How about LLDB? Hot take: the only good thing about VS is the IDE, if you don't use it, I would move away from their tools: MSVC (in favor of Clang or GCC), debugger (in favor of LLDB or GDB), and perhaps even STL (in favor of libstdc++ or libc++).

Comment: Is WinDbg the debugger visual studio uses? Or visual studio has its own debugger? If yes, then what is its filename and does it support command line interface?

Comment: yes [Headless debugging on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59978054/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line:
devenv /DebugExe ProgramName.exe [ProgramArgs]