# Exception logging for MFC projects? (Encountered an improper argument)

Tags: exception, mfc, error-logging

In C# they have nice tools like `SimpleLogger` to record all exception info.

But I can’t find anything like that to use with my MFC application. I use the various `try` / `catch` mechanisms but sometimes I get a sporadic error message display in **release** build only:

> Encountered an improper argument

Sadly, it can’t be raised on demand but has appeared a few times in recent weeks.

There was one instance when the error displayed whilst I was recording a video tutorial with **Debut** software. Here is the screen grab:

[image]

Is there anyway to log better information about exceptions when they happen because this popup message is not helping me find the problem.

---

I stumbled across this interesting [article](https://waelalghool.blogspot.com/2012/01/mfc-encountered-improper-argument.html) where it mentions this about `ENSURE`:

```
#define ENSURE(cond) ENSURE_THROW(cond, ::AfxThrowInvalidArgException() )
```

I use `ENSURE` when I load all my STRINGTABLE resources and a few other bits. But I don't think this is my problem.

Comment: Exception handling 101: Do not `catch` exceptions. When following this rule, any exception causes your process to [terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate). That's a safe and sane option. Worst case: Users lose unsaved data. That sounds terrible, until you evaluate the alternatives, like irrecoverably corrupting user data, or providing remote code execution attack opportunities. Added bonus: You can set up your debugger to [break on unhandled exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger).

Comment: This is approximately correct. There are situations where you can safely handle exceptions and there are situations where you MUST NOT EVER let exceptions propagate.

Comment: About 80% of my `ENSURE` calls across my project were OK (using `LoadString`). I assume that they do not need to be changed to `VERIFY`. For all the other pointer / null checks I changed to `ASSERT`. And for one or two that test the return value of a function I now use `VERIFY`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle "*anyway to log better information about exceptions when they happen*" Save a [crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252338/what-is-a-dump-file-in-windows-task-manager) file (before OK'ing the error box), then load it in VS or WinDbg for debugging.

Comment: @dxiv I tried to use the `__try` etc. that was in the linked article but it wouldn't compile in a MFC Dialog app. It had a problem with ability to unwind the stack.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle `__try/__catch` can work in C++, but it requires [`/EHa`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-160) to unwind the stack in all cases, as explained on the [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160) page.

Comment: @dxiv I could not work out how to activate that switch in the the settings panel. And, I am concerned about any impact on my existing app behaviour if I make this change?

Comment: @dxiv At the top of that article is says: "... we recommend that you use ISO-standard C++ exception handling.".

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Right, I meant to just answer the "*how to*" part, not necessarily recommend it. In the IDE `/EHa` is one of the options under C/C++ / Code Generation / Enable C++ Exceptions. Whether/when to use it is a longer story, and the linked SEH pages give some hints about that.

Answer (score 2):

From recollection, this is exactly about the `AfxThrowInvalidArgException()` mentioned in the question. Thus, it can be helpful to do a debugger attach on the process, add a breakpoint on `AfxThrowInvalidArgException` (and `CInvalidArgException::CInvalidArgException` ctor), and hopefully hit the location (throw site) where this happens the next time.

A usual error site of this mechanism also is around dialog DDX handling (invalid arguments/range).

This gem ranks quite high on my favourites list ("how to screw up usability massively by not mentioning any helpful reference/context info in an error message whatsoever").